# ASP.NET MVC default routh is wrong

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-routing

I got simple web application with 1 default routing:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Game", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

My controller contains the following actions:

```
public class GameController : Controller
{   
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        // some actions            
        return View();
    }                     

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CreateGame(Game game, User user)
    {
        // some actions
            return View("Game");                      
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult JoinGame(User user)
    {
        // some actions
        return View("Game");                        
    }
}
```

Also under Views/Game folder I got "Index" and "Game" views.
But when I start application from time to time (NOT ALWAYS!) it requests

```
http://localhost:55815/Game/Game
```

instead of

```
http://localhost:55815 or http://localhost:55815/Game/Index
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Your application default route is working fine.**

The debugger starts url `http://localhost:55815/Game/Game`  because the file `Game.cshtml` is currently opened in your Visual Studio.

The solution is on your VisualStudio project configuration. 
**Choose specific page with empty value instead of current/active Page**.

[image]

Comment: OK, I got 1 thing in my mind - OMG! Serious! I debugged it for a few hours! &%$#^@$#$#*%$(^(^% ... grrrrr
Thanks a lot man!

Answer (score 0):

Actually,

> /Game/Game

and

> /Game/Index

are both the same. When you check you default routing file you can see that your main controller is written with predefined controller and action. So the program automatically resolve this url according to that. Mostly try your web application not in visual studio debug but put it under IIS than if you need debugging, debug IIS instance.

Good luck